# Enforce missing Javadoc on subclasses

Tags: java, javadoc

Maybe this question has been answered and I didn't see any good responses from my searches.

Is it possible to enforce missing Javadoc on subclasses when the method is overridden? By default Javadoc goes up too the super class and the doc generation doesnt complain.

I'd like to enforce strict doc standards even on subclasses as crazy as that sounds, and missing params and returns isn't allowed regardless of the implementation.

Comment: Are the subclasses all ones in your code base, or are you publishing them to a third party and want to enforce it on them as well? The latter isn't possible, but tools may help with the former. Are you using maven, jenkins, or some other build tool?

Comment: @yshavit yes Gradle

Comment: I don't know Gradle, but check to see if there's a checkstyle plugin or similar that can enforce this. More than that, I don't know. :)